# Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null - Anyone kow how to fix?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get some help here, I'm getting the following error: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

This is for my forum for my website, here is the line it is showing on laravel as where the error is:

```
   $thread = ForumThread::where('id', '=', $id)->with(['topic'])->firstOrFail();
```

Could someone correct this for me? I'm not too sure on what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried to fix this myself but have no clue what I'm doing! Hopefully there's someone out there that can help :)

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please provide your `ForumThread` model, particularly the `topic`  relationship you have defined ... my guess is you are not returning anything from that method

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, this means you are not returning anything from your relationship method that you defined, `topic`. You have to return some `Relation` type object from this methods. Most likely you are just forgetting the `return` part. For example the method should look like this:

```
public function topic()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Topic::class);
}
```

My guess is that you are forgetting the `return` part of that statement.